# Increment FieldValue using QuerySnapshot

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform a query on a collection, and if the document exists I want to increment a counter. This is for tracking number of accesses. Unfortunately, the following code does not work and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. I am trying to minimize Firestore reads.

```js
db = firebase.firestore(admin);
var users = db.collection("users");
var query = users
  .where("userid", "==", userid)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
      var docRef = querySnapshot.docs[0];

      // does not work
      const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
      docRef.update("accessCount", increment);

      // also does not work
      var theDoc = db.collection("users").doc(docRef.id);
      console.log(theDoc);
      const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
      theDoc.update("accessCount", increment);
    }
  })
```

Note, I'm getting a valid docRef, but it doesn't seem I can do anything with it except get the data from within... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts here:

```
var docRef = querySnapshot.docs[0];
```

What you're getting here is not a document *reference*, but a document *snapshot*. When you later call `docRef.update()`, that won't work because a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) doesn't have an `update` method. You should actually be getting an error message there, which also keeps the rest of your code from runnung.

Something like this should work:

```
if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
  var docRef = querySnapshot.docs[0].ref;
  docRef.update("accessCount", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));
}
```